# R sqldf SELECT when col may be missing

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a number of .csv files. Certain columns appear in all files, but some others only appear in some files. There are also many other columns I don't want.

I'm using R sqldf to iterate through the .csv files, select the desired columns, and write it to a new .csv file. However, I don't know how to tell sqldf that some columns may not be found in some of the .csv files, in which case I want it to create it anyway (even though it will be blank).

In the example below, the column `userlocation1` only appears in some of the .csv files. So the code doesn't work if a file doesn't have it.

I've tried try-catch but that just caused that some files weren't processed at all.

```
for (fileNumber in fileNumbers){
  newfileName <- paste(sub(paste("\\.", sep = ""), "", fileNames[fileNumber]),
                       "-clean", ".csv", sep = "")
  tx <- paste(readLines(fileNames[fileNumber], encoding="UTF-8"), collapse="%%%")  
  tx_as_table <- fread(text = tx, header = TRUE, sep = ",", nrows = 501, 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fill = TRUE, select = 1:50)  
  dfmediaurl <- sqldf('select created_at, text, id_str, in_reply_to_status_id, 
                username1, userscreen_name1, userlocation1 from tx_as_table')
  write.table(x = dfmediaurl, file = newfileName, append = FALSE, quote = TRUE, sep 
              = ";", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To refer to all columns use `*` as shown in this example with the builtin `anscombe` data frame:

```
sqldf("select * from anscombe limit 3")
##   x1 x2 x3 x4   y1   y2    y3   y4
## 1 10 10 10  8 8.04 9.14  7.46 6.58
## 2  8  8  8  8 6.95 8.14  6.77 5.76
## 3 13 13 13  8 7.58 8.74 12.74 7.71
```

or to show only certain columns such that the table may not have some of them then `intersect` the column names with those actually in the table creating a character vector of column names to use, convert that to a comma separated string using `toString` and insert that into the SQL statement.  Note that `fn$` must prefix `sqldf` to enable string interpolation.  `verbose=TRUE` will also display the SQL statement that is run (i.e. it will also show the output lines that begin with `sqldf:` below -- note that the second last `sqldf:` line in the output displays the generated SQL statement):

```
# use those columns among x3, x4 and x5 that are in anscombe
cols <- toString(intersect(c("x3", "x4", "x5"), names(anscombe)))

fn$sqldf("select $cols from anscombe limit 3", verbose = TRUE)
## sqldf: library(RSQLite)
## sqldf: m <- dbDriver("SQLite")
## sqldf: connection <- dbConnect(m, dbname = ":memory:")
## sqldf: initExtension(connection)
## sqldf: dbWriteTable(connection, 'anscombe', anscombe, row.names = FALSE)
## sqldf: dbGetQuery(connection, 'select x3, x4 from anscombe limit 3')
## sqldf: dbDisconnect(connection)
##   x3 x4
## 1 10  8
## 2  8  8
## 3 13  8
```